# Is the following set Countable or Uncountable?

Tags: set, context-free-grammar

Is the set of all context free grammars with exactly the terminals {0,1,2} and exactly the non-terminals {S,T,R} countable or uncountable? Is it infinite?

Comment: It's a subset of the set of all Turing machines, so it can be no more than countably infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zack answered in the comments above it is a set of all Turing Machines therefore it can not be any more than countably infinite.